# How can I pass My geolocation data to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, geolocation

want pass output data of my geolocation api to firebase how can ı do ıt?

```
 const start= document.querySelector("#Başlat")
 const stop= document.querySelector("#Durdur")

 start.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data=>{
        console.log(data);

    });
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to send it inside the `getCurrentPosition()` callback. Same place you currently log it. This would also be a good time to thoroughly read [ask]. Your question is overly broad as written and doesn't show any attempts of your own to solve your issue

Comment: thanks for answer should you show how can ı embed inside callback i realy stucked at this position

Comment: @GökdenizCetin What about the code you shared doesn't work? So: when you run this code fragment, what line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: hi sir actually  ım  newbie at stackoferflow my exact problem about this code is how can ı send it into firebase, i havent find out the solution.

Comment: Sending data to firebase is well documented. Suggest you work on some basic tutorials first. SO isn't really a *"how to"* tutorial service. Once you get the basics of sending and receiving simple data to/from firebase working and have some actual problems integrating into sending the geolocation data, come back then with your attempts and debugging details

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try this:

```
const start= document.querySelector("#Başlat")
const stop= document.querySelector("#Durdur")
const db = firebase.database();    

start.addEventListener("click",()=>{
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(data=>{
    db.ref('your ref path here').set(data);

});
```

});